# Run class from a service Android

Tags: android, web-services, service, android-asynctask

The WebService_modificar class has implemented the connections to the database and, through the .PHP file, updates the date, coordinates, etc ... captured in my EditText, saving it in my remote bbdd (I must point out that to execute CLASS WebService_modificar from the Main it is perfect). But now I want the date updates, coordinates to be carried out in the background by the CLASS Service.
But I can not do the same from my service, I can not put ActivityMain.this as context. How should I run 'classJava' from my onStartCommand method of my Service?

```
    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(LocationUpdatesService.EXTRA_LOCATION);

            et_fechahora.setText(devuelveFechaHora());

            //Aquí hay que meter el webService actualizar
            new WebService_modificar(MainActivity.this).execute();
```

Now I want to run my WebService_Modify class from my Service in the onStartCommand method so that I get the time in the background, but I get an error.

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service started");
    boolean startedFromNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION,
            false);

    // We got here because the user decided to remove location updates from the notification.
    if (startedFromNotification) {
        removeLocationUpdates();
        stopSelf();
    }
    // Le dice al sistema que SI intente volver a crear el servicio después de que se haya eliminado.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Here I leave the link to the project on GitHub to see its more complete visualization, and thus be able to solve the error. In short, I need to send updates to the bbdd in the background. When it runs and is in the foreground, it does it perfectly. Let's see if we can find the solution.

https://github.com/Chiscu/kakao

Comment: Hi Chiscu, please read [how to post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getApplicationContext()` inside a service, instead of `MainActivity.this`

#### EDIT:

From your update i see you need Context in a BroadcastReceiver for your WebService.
Why not use the Context you get in `onReceive` as parameter?

This context is [the Context in which the receiver is running](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent))

If you need a Context in `onStartCommand` inside a Service, `getApplicationContext()` should work.

By the way the link to your code isn't working.

Comment: Are you sure your service class actually extends [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service)?

Comment: I get an error because I'm calling a class from the service class, and this is called from ActivityMain

Comment: yes, and trying to execute the Java class from the onStartCommand () method

Comment: Hello, I have reissued the question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the debugging that you have achieved with the error. The reason for it was that he had modified the values ​​of the fields of the base with the values ​​of the text edition, and of course when the class Service web_modify was executed from the Main (first plane), the data changed, and he took it for modify them in the bbdd without problem. **Being the ActivityMain in the background I can not take the values ​​of the fields but also the methods from which the date and other data is obtained.**

In the same way thank you all for your comments, because they have served me to be able to investigate and be more on top of the code.